# Probability that a random variable X belongs to the set of rational nos.

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

The question is a Multiple choice question

Let $X$ be a random variable with the M.G.F. $$M_{X}(t) = \frac{6}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{e^{\frac{t^2}{2n}}}{n^2}\,,\;t\in R$$
Then $P(X \in Q)$, where $\,Q$ is the set of rational nos., equals

The options are

1. 0
2. 1/4
3. 1/2
4. 3/4

The correct option is option 1.) i.e. 0

I'm looking for an explanation as to how did they deduce the answer to zero.

Comment: Hint: Which distribution has this $M_X$ as MGF?

Comment: I can't think of any standard distribution that has the MGF as that of $M_X$

Comment: And the MGF $t\mapsto e^{t^2/2n}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ be a random variable with pmf $P(Y=n)=\frac{6}{n^2\pi^2}$ and $Z|Y=n\sim N(0,1/n).$ Then $Z$ has the pmf $M_X(t).$ So, $Z$ and $X$ have same distribution. $P(X\in \mathbb{Q})=P(Z\in \mathbb{Q})=\sum_{n\geq 1}P(Z\in \mathbb{Q}|Y=n)P(Y=n)=\sum_{n\geq 1}0\times P(Y=n)=0.$

Comment: I've some questions in regards to the solution. Firstly is the sum of P(Y=n) 1 over all the possible values of n. Secondly, for X and Z to have the same distribution they need should have the same MGF. Thirdly how is the pmf of Z equal to $M_X(t)$ shouldn't there be a $\sqrt{2\pi}$ term in the denominator of $M_X(t)$

Comment: $Z$ doesn't have pmf, it has pdf. And I made a correction in $P(Y=n).$